# Upload image using CodeIgniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, image-upload

PLease help me on how to upload image in the folder and the same time in the database with a random name.
There's an error: Call to a member function getName() on null.
Heres my code in controller

```
`public function actionInsert()
{
$destination = new DestinationModel();
$name=$this->request->getVar('name');
$place=$this->request->getVar('place');
$location=$this->request->getVar('location');
$category=$this->request->getVar('category');
$description=$this->request->getVar('description');
$latitude=$this->request->getVar('latitude');
$longitude=$this->request->getVar('longitude');

$image=$this->request->getFile('image');
$imageName = $image->getName();
$image->move('im/destination', $imageName);

if($place == 'Calapan City')
{
$place = 'Calapan';
}else if($category == 'Destination')
{
$category ='Destination';
}
$data = [
'name' => $name,
'place' => $place,
'location' => $location,
'category' => $category,
'image' => $place. '/'. $imageName,
'description' => $description,
'latitude' => $latitude,
'longitude' => $longitude
];
$destination->save($data);
return view('adding_place');
}`
```

Comment: check if you have 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' in form_open()